# Ajax call fails and returns [object Object]

Tags: plugins, ajax

I have created a plugin which in I want to send an ajax call and update my database accordingly.

But now when I test my ajax call it fails and returns `[object Object]` and I cant figure out why.

Ajax action hook:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax', 'my_ajax');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax', 'my_ajax' );
function my_ajax(){

    echo "test";
    wp_die();

}
```

Ajax JS call:

```
function updateDB(name, email, address, co_address, city){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'my_ajax',
            //pictureURL: picUrl,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            address: address,
            co_address: co_address,
            city: city
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success: " + data);
            //clearInputfields();
            //successMessage();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("fail: " + data);
        }
    });
}
```

When I call updateDB I get: `fail: [object Object]`.

I have not configured the wordpress ajax plugin myself. But I it works since we are using it on other parts of our site.

What could be wrong? Do I need to provide more info?

**EDIT:**

I did this to get the contents of the object:

```
for(var property in Object) {
    alert(property + "=" + obj[property]);
}
```

This returned: `undefined`

Kinda expected though.

**EDIT 2:**

I removed my comments in my original post so my action hook now looks like this:

```
global $wpdb;

// If validation has no errors, insert data
if ( $wpdb->insert('fellotest.orders',
    array(
        'picUrl' => $_POST['picURL'],
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'address' => $_POST['address'],
        'co_address' => $_POST['co_address'],
        'city' => $_POST['city']
        ),
    array(
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'
    )
)) {
    // If $wpdb->insert was successful, send success message back to AJAX updateDB function
    wp_send_json_success(array('message' => 'Successfully uploaded!'));

} else {
    // If insert was unsuccessfull, send error message back to AJAX
    wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Error: Something went wrong'));
}

wp_die();
```

And when I call it with the new error function:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR);
    console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
    console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
}
```

I get this as result:

```
jqXHR: [object Object]
textStatus: parsererror
errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4
```

**SOLUTION:**

I am sorry but the error was really stupid, I read the network tab and saw what database table i tried to insert it into. And apperently it was preconfigured to another database table. So instead of what I have fellotest.orders It tried to insert it into fello.fellotest.orders. So I moved my table to fello database and altered my insert into simply orders and now it works!

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log('failed'); console.log(data);`

Comment: @czerspalace Then I get `failed
VM3305:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:36`

Comment: Have you tried to respond with `wp_send_json`?

Comment: Also the correct use of `error` is `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`. Try to print the errors to see why it fails

Comment: You can also try to remove the `dataType: 'json',`, you are expecting a json response but sending text from your server function

Comment: @Laxmana Please see edit 2

Comment: @czerspalace Please see edit 2

Comment: What happens if you remove `dataType: 'json',`? The error is telling you that it cannot parse the data that is returned from the server. You should try using the network monitor in console tools to see what data is being returned from the server.

Comment: @czerspalace I solved it. I am sorry but the error was really stupid, I read the network tab and saw what database table i tried to insert it into. And apperently it was preconfigured to another database table. So instead of what I have `fellotest.orders` It tried to insert it into `fello.fellotest.orders`. So I moved my table to fello database and altered my insert into simply `orders` and now it works!

Comment: You should use $wpdb->prepare to protect against Sql injections and I would suggest testing that the post contains the posts variables if(isset($_POST['picURL']) && isset($_POST['name']) ) and then you can validate or do other required actions prior to inserting.